# Trying to convert a string into a time format using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i like to import a dataset with pandas, this is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(source + 'clustering_CB\\AAA_tableau_jan_oct_19_cardiologia.txt' ,sep='\t' , engine='python')
```

Column Col10 contains string values which let me know the duration of a web visit, here's an example

```
00:02:35
```

2 minute and 35 seconds. 
What i like to do is to import this columns as a time format in order to measure (in seconds or in minutes) the duration of the web visit.

Comment: use `pd.to_timedelta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the column already contains timedelta values (in string format) - in this case, you can apply the `pd.to_timedelta` function to the column:

```py
timedelta = pd.to_timedelta(df["Col10"])
```

Comment: yess, thank you but i was guessing if this could be possible while importing data

Comment: @lucapellerossapelles I think you can, using the `converters` keyword in the `read_csv` function call. I've never used it myself, but I think it should be able to do this as well. You can read more [in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)